# How can I require external commonjs modules at runtime from a bundle that was built by webpack

Tags: webpack

In a customer project there is kind of a plugin system.
It works this way:
JS files are located at a certain directory. Let's say `/plugins`.

Those plugins export a function that has a common signature.

Now I'm bundling the rest of the code with webpack. I want to dynamically load those modules via `require(someVar)`.

Since I don't know the plugin files at build time, they cannot be bundled with webpack.

I tried to create some externals, like this with no luck:

```js
externals: [
  (_context, request, callback) =>
    /^\/plugins\/.*$/.test(request)
      ? callback(null, `commonjs ${request}`)
      : callback(),
],
```

At runtime it throws an error like this:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/plugins/file.js'
    at webpackEmptyContext (filex.js:line:col)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:594:20)
```

How can I not bundle those files and require them at runtime from the file system? Is this even possible with webpack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution:

```
const dynamicRequire =
  typeof __webpack_require__ === "function" ? __non_webpack_require__ : require;
```

This works with webpack and ts-node (I use ts-node in development time).